# Enforce strict outbound ports (or ranges) for protocol

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

Is it possible to narrow the allowed range of outbound ports that can be used for a specific protocol (e.g. HTTP(S))?  I understand that, by default, the system will randomly allocate any available port but is that configurable to use a specific one?

Comment: use `mangle table` of 'iptables'.With `mangle` you can doing traffic shaping.

Answer (score 1):

No, it makes little sense anyway. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: to get a controllable handle on the network interface -- within some ranges.  E.g. if i wanted some protocol to stay away from some port segments.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @rahmu The question was "is it possible"; it's not automatically an invalid answer just because it has a question mark in it

Comment: It's not about the question mark. It's about the request for clarification. It's clearly stated in the auto-comment, I didn't invent it. Thank you for assuming I do these review tasks mechanically without putting thoughts into it. Highly appreciated.

Comment: @vonbrand: I still think the answer is very poorly worded. It should have more explanations. What makes you say that it's a "No" without doubt, as opposed to a "I don't know how to do it"?

Comment: The answer is no because the kernel has no idea what protocol is going to be used when you open/connect the socket.